# Check whether the value present or not

Tags: java, api, request

I want to check whether  the request body contains an integer value or not?

Example Request body :

```
{
    "testint":0,
    "xxx":"yy"
}

{
    "xxx":"yy"
}
```

how to check whether "testint" is present in the request body or not

Comment: you mean inside a json?

Comment: unmarshall and test if null ?

Comment: this is not a valid json. Nevertheless parse the json and do a null check.

Comment: Can you give some more information about what libraries and frameworks you are using? For example, is this a web service written in Spring?

Comment: @Stultuske yes. inside json request body

Comment: @Sam yes Spring. but not interested in validators.

Comment: @Myth in that case, could you update the code to make it clear that you're using Spring and maybe include a code example of the controller method that is reading the request?

Comment: why is it so hard to understand.?